# "Multiplying" a white background gives perfect results! how do I save this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

This is my original image in a layer... on top of a pattern bg

[image]

as you can see, it has a white background. I would love for it to be transparent.

When I change its blending mode to "Multiply" it becomes transparent as you can see in the image below

[image]

This transparency is nearly perfect. I cannot reach even 10% of the quality of this white background stripping by any mean, magic eraser, color replacing etc. nothing works like this blending mode.

How can I use the same "technique" to create a saved transparent PNG of my image? without any forced background? This is really my goal here. I'd like to strip it of its white background in the best way possible without working on every pixel for weeks...  how do I apply the same "blending" technique that stripped the image of its white background in order to **save it** transparent?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way that I know of that this is possible. It's bothered me for years.

Comment: You can subtract the white of the image.

Comment: how do i "subtract the white"?

Comment: Gimp has a "color to alpha" which seems to be exactly what you want. According to [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/does-photoshop-have-an-equivalent-to-gimps-color-to-alpha), Photoshop doesn't have such an option, but I don't use Photoshop. [Example.](http://i.imgur.com/TL72S9f.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no solid way to get the same appearance as the multiply blend mode. But **you can get exceptionally close** with very little effort.

Just <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-click the thumbnail for the Blue Channel in the **Channel Panel**. (should then see marching ants)

Highlight the layer in the **Layer Panel** and add a new mask.

Invert the mask

Use **Levels** or **Curves** to boost the contrast of the mask.

[image]

I find **Channels** are quite often one of the best and fastest way to create a mask, especially if the area being removed is consistent (like a white background).

Comment: With a little bit of more work one can get even closer. At minimum you should remove the white fringes by running matting white matte. Tough this is not a big deal if the new background is allwa light colored.

Comment: Good point @joojaa Using multiply basically *kills* all white. At least with this method you can retain *some* of the highlights in the inner image area. Perhaps not the 100% white, but you don't darken anything the way multiply does.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Scott's answer, you could use the Blending Options for the layer. Just lowering blend if option:

[image]

Gave me a pretty good result:

[image]

Comment: You might even want to Alt-click that arrow at 190 to separate it into two halves and have a gradient effect instead of a hard cut-off.

Comment: As well as what Vincent suggests to lose the unnatural hard edges, you should move that arrow much further to the right - it's taking too much of the highlights. You're losing all the shadows and lots of details on the people: some are just a head floating above a pair of legs!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer select the white Area with the magic wand tool and go to `Select > Refine Edge` or press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and adjust the setting as you may want.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In any program with blend modes you can always use multiply on your original, export it with transparency (png). Open NEW empty project and put in the new file you just exported. Duplicate it until it seems like all the transparency is gone, then go into the lowest layer with a white solid (or brush) and put whites under only the needed area. Export with transparency again.

This should get you a better version of multiply with no white background. I'm guessing it's slower than some other method... but if you're a little creative there's more than one way to do the same thing in these workstations.. and that's a good thing.

Comment: I can't understand how this answers the question... What you are saying is the opposite of what's being asked